# How to ordinal form date using DATE_FORMAT()?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

My Mysql query

```
select DATE_FORMAT(max(lastmodified), '%d %M %y , %r') from client_log
```

and my actuall output is

[image]

i want result 15th june 16, 02:17:09PM, i have to apply this ordinal concept in php logic but here i don't know how to perform in date_format() function or is there any function available for mysql in timestamp filed?

Comment: So, you're looking for the PHP way to do the same? It's usually a lot easier/faster to just fetch the data from your database in the desired format, rather than to have PHP re-process the information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is %d and it should be %D

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

```
  select DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%D %M %y , %r') ;
    +-------------------------------------+
    | DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%D %M %y , %r') |
    +-------------------------------------+
    | 27th June 16 , 02:57:00 PM          |
    +-------------------------------------+
    1 row in set (0.04 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this Format.

```
select DATE_FORMAT(max(lastmodified), '%D %M %y , %r') from client_log
```